# TypeError raised even if the variable seems to be of the right type

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, file, binary

Considering the following code portion:

```
txt = 'Some text, dude!'
with open('to_load', mode='wb') as f:
   raw = txt.encode('ascii')
   print(raw, file=f)
```

Could anybody please explain why a `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'` exception is raised inside `print`, even if the `raw` variable seems to be of binary data type?

```
(Pdb) type(raw)
<class 'bytes'>
```

Even using `bytes`, the exception is still raised:

```
raw = bytes(txt.encode('ascii'))
```

Comment: You didn't read `print`'s documentation, did you?

Comment: @KellyBundy, I supposed that the `__doc__` already included all the information. Anyway, thanks: I read the doc on Python website and I got the point.

Comment: The issue here isn't raw, the following code prints fine:

    txt = 'Some text, dude!'
    with open('to_load', mode='wb') as f:
        raw = txt.encode('ascii')
        print(raw)`

The `file=f` is your issue, I'm not sure what you are trying to do with this.

Comment: @Brian They're obviously trying to print to the file, nothing unusual, that's why that parameter exists.

Comment: @rudicangiotti Yeah, doc strings are usually shorter than the full documentation.

Comment: As I supposed just some minutes after (is the only logical explanation), `print` converts everything to string before doing the actual print (to console or to file). So, writing a string to a binary file object raises exception.

Comment: @KellyBundy I meant in the context, there may be a better way to achieve the solution rather than printing an entire file.

Comment: @Brian they aren't printing a file, they are *writing to a file*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, thanks for clearing up my ignorance here. I never used that syntax and misread this. Thanks.